# Get rid of the [annoyances] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I was surprised to see that we have a tag called [annoyances](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/annoyances) (99 questions). Really?

Burninate it, fast! Trogdor, I summon you!

[image: trogdor signal]

It is obvious that this is a useless meta-tag, that adds no valuable information to a question other than making people rant even more.

Comment: Sorry, I just *had* to use it!

Comment: This question should be tagged [annoyances]. Because bad tags are.

Comment: the [annoyances] tag should be removed from all windows related posts as it is redundant there.

Comment: @DanD. These comments are so … annoying!

Comment: @kinokijuf Do you know what "sarcasm" means?

Comment: @slhck I sarcastically added the tag.

Comment: We all love the occasional fun on Meta, but there's no need to bump a post unnecessarily – **just to add the tag we are discussing to remove**. As a friendly reminder, which is definitely the first one you received, you should definitely consider taking your editing privileges more seriously than this. On Meta, and on the main site. @kin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Trogdor!]

(:

Comment: dununun NAH dununun NAH dununun nun nuh nAAAAAAAAHHHHH!